# Resistor parallel to optocoupler LED in Zener-stabilized circuit

Tags: power-supply, opto-isolator, stability

I was watching a video about phone chargers where the following schematics was presented:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqv6Sn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the video it was stated that this schematics is for the feedback circuit of a phone charger and that the resistor R1 is for stabilizing the optocoupler.

**Question 1:** How does the resistor stabilize the optocoupler, and why would one need to stabilize the optocoupler?

**Question 2:** I would argue that the voltage drop over R1 is limited to the forward voltage drop of the diode within the optocoupler. Does that make sense? If so - Why would one place a resistor there, doesn't that limit the current supplied to the led, resulting in a slower turn on time for the transistor of the optocoupler?

Thank you for your help :)

For reference video (**Timestamp: 08:20**): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNoGCdX1IdQ&t=500s

Comment: Is that schematic correct?  The 1N4733 zener shown is a 5.1V device.  Wired as shown, it would never turn on, and would therefore conduct no current (except for leakage) with the 1V source shown.  Hence the opto would never turn on.

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks for pointing that out, I've removed the 1N4733 label for I have no value for the zener.  But still I'd like to know how such a resistor effects the zener.

Comment: The circuit that's shown still has problems.  There should always be a resistor in series with the opto's diode in order to limit the current through the diode.  The parallel resistor shown is to prevent charge buildup,  noise or an EMC coupled voltage spike on the input lines to the opto's diode from turning on the opto.  I'll try to find a representative circuit from one of our designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-voltage Zener Diodes tend to have a significant amount of leakage current while the voltage is below or near the Zener voltage. This causes the opto-coupler to start turning on too early.

Adding a resistor in parallel with the Zener Diode swamps out the effect of the leakage current. That, in turn, makes the regulation voltage much more accurate.

[Edit]

Placing a fairly-low value resistor in parallel with the LED in the opto-coupler causes the combination of the resistor and LED to require more current before the LED begins to turn ON.  This extra current must come through the Zener Diode.

The Zener leakage current is still there but that leakage current results in much less voltage across the LED.  As you may recall, the transfer function for a LED is such that the LED will not consume significant current below the turn-on voltage of the LED.

If you choose the appropriate value of resistor, the LED begins to turn ON when the voltage across the Zener Diode is close or very close to its rated voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain more how placing a resistor in parallel with a zener Diode 'swamps out the effect of the leakage current'?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "standard" circuit we use for driving opto-couplers.

[image: Opto-coupler]

R269 & R268 serve to limit the current to the opto's diode.

D26 protects against a reverse voltage on the interface.

C180, along with R269 & R268 provide some rudimentary noise filtering.

And R265 provides for charge bleedoff.

Note - no zener in series with the opto's diode.

One more thing to note - this circuit is for interfaces that switch infrequently and have no real speed requirement, such as turning on a power supply.  There's a slightly different configuration used when more speed is required, such as sending clocks across the interface.

Comment: This does not answer the question what the purpose of R1 is.

Comment: R265 in my schematic is the same as R1 in the OP's schematic.  I gave you the reason for R265.  But I am not a mind reader and so I do not know what was going through the head of the person who created that design/schematic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Steve, what do you mean by 'R265 is for the charge bleed off'

Comment: Without a spec on data rate, skew error,  CMRR and driver specs,  this could be bad example

Comment: Depends on the use.  The schematic shown above is for a power supply enable interface, so the date rate is 0.00027 Hz, max <wink>.  Understand about the other points you mentioned.  In passed muster by our SMEs and with a WCCA signed off by our customer and their consultants.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question 1**

For a Zener diode to provide its rated Zener voltage with good regulation, a reverse bias current must be injected on the order of one or some milliamps. This level of current might be undesirable especially for low power applications, but necessary. A characteristic of the Zener diode generally quoted in the relevant datasheets is the rating of the test current. Depending on the value of V1, a much lower forward current than the Zener test current might circulate in the optocoupler, not enough for the Zener diode to stabilize the voltage. A resistor in parallel to the optocoupler is like a current generator for the Zener diode, forcing the circulation of appropriate current in addition to the small LED one.

Imagine an internal parasitic variable resistance in parallel to the ideally perfect Zener diode. With voltage below the Zener value, while the Zener diode would be in interdiction region, the internal resistor still supplies some small current to the optocoupler (which is transferred to the phototransistor considering that optocouplers are generally linear in a power supply feedback circuit, acting as a current amplifier), so the Zener parasitic resistance dimly lights the LED even at a lower voltage than the Zener value, significantly reducing the stability of the circuit. Adding a low resistance in parallel to the LED drops the effect of the parasitic resistance.

For a better understanding of this Zener characteristic, take for instance the following [Zener Breakdown diagram](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85765/dz23.pdf) representing, at a certain temperature, how the actual reverse-breakdown voltage Vz of the device varies as a function of the reverse current Iz and depending on the various Zener nominal voltages (2.7V, 3.3V, 3.9V, 4.7V. 5.6V, 6.8V, 8.2V).

[image]

An ideal Zener diode should show a vertical line, positioned to its Zener nominal voltage; a resistor should show a straight line intersecting the origin. In the diagram, for low voltage Zener devices (like the 2.7V Zener), the related curve close to the origin appears more or less like the one of a resistor (notice the segment with very low milliamps, e.g. below 2 mA, which is still within the typical optocoupler forward current range). The higher the bias current, the more stable the voltage.

The drawback of this feedback circuit in an SMPS is that even in no-load conditions a current circulates through the resistor to keep the Zener appropriately biased (even if there are techniques to reduce it).

**Answer to question 2**

The resistor R1 drops the LED voltage when V1 is sensibly below the Zener voltage; in this condition, the LED internal resistance is high. When V1 > Vzener, the voltage over both R1 and the LED is V1 - Vzener, not significantly influenced by R1 value in ideal condition; this lights the LED according to its forward voltage characteristics.

For appropriate circuit design, the current over R1 should be in line with the test current of the Zener (e.g., 5 milliamps), so that the Zener is always biased, even if the LED is powered with a very small current (e.g., 0,5 mA).